# FQL Query not getting a response

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

My javascript solution for pulling in the likes for a set of links on a certain page is no longer working. I can't find anything wrong, and I've tried using the .api() method (below) and the Data.query() method but neither is working. This is the code that I currently have and it's similar to what I was using when it was working.

```
var inlist = [url1, url2, url3..... urln];

FB.api(
  {
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN('+inlist.substr(0, inlist.length-2)+')'
  },
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    for( var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++ ) {
      if (response[i]['total_count'] > 0){
        $(vids[response[i]['url']]).append("<div class='likes'>"+response[i]['total_count']+"</div>");
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The console reports nothing, my FB object is initialized correctly (the example queries run with no problem), and the URL's are generated dynamically based on a list of links. Also, it's worth mentioning that I tested the FQL here:http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/ and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that I was including too many IN(...) items. Oddly enough though there was no error, just no response. I limited the items in to 10 and everything started working again.

```
for(var i=0 ; i < Math.ceil(inlist.length/10); i++) {
  FB.api(
    {
      method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN('+inlist.slice((10*i), ((i+1)*10)).join(', ')+')'
    },
    function(response){
      for( var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++ ) {
        ...
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using `substr` on an array but this is how I would do it:

```
var inlist = ['www.facebook.com','www.masteringapi.com'];
FB.api(
{
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url IN("'+inlist.join('","')+'")'
},
function(response) {
    for( var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++ ) {
      if (response[i]['total_count'] > 0){
        console.log(response[i]['url'] + ': ' + response[i]['total_count'] + ' likes');
      }
    }
}
);
```

This would return something like:

> www.facebook.com: 36643537 likes
>   www.masteringapi.com: 26 likes